# The method setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type imageButton1

Tags: android

I  keep getting this error message and I am not sure what I am supposed to do.

The method `setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){})` is undefined for the type `imageButton1`

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    

    imageButton1 imagebutton1 = (imageButton1) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
         ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
         iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
imageButton1.setOnClickListener ....
```

ImageButton is the name of the class, imageButton1 the name of your instance of the class.

Comment: how would i go about making an app that holds a bunch of widgets kind of like beautiful widgets