# The method findViewByID(int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Tags: android

I am getting the above error in the following code in Button and EditText. I just don't know why it is coming. If you guys can understand and tell me what exactly went wrong here, it will be great.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.btn_OK);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent data = new Intent();

                EditText txt_username = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.txt_username);
                data.setData(Uri.parse(txt_username.getText().toString()));
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I have tried to see in the link  [The method setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type imageButton1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247331/the-method-setonclicklistenernew-view-onclicklistener-is-undefined-for-the)  but its not usable for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a typo:

is   `EditText txt_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username)`;

not  `EditText txt_username = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.txt_username);`

the last letter, the **d**, is lowercase

Comment: yeah got it and sorry I over looked it. Thanks PAL ! :)

Comment: This should not cause the described error... Although you're right.

Answer (score 1):

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // ...
    EditText txt_username = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.txt_username);
    //...
  }
}
```

This is an "anonymous inner class" (of type `View.OnClickListener`). The `findViewById()`-method is from the `Activity`-class, which is not the current scope. Use this:

```
Activity2.this.findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
```

This will get the context of the outer class (`Activity`) and enable you to use it's instance-methods.

Answer (score 0):

`findViewByID()` is owned by the Activity class. OnClickListener is another class and has its own functions and methods. You are basically trying to call a function `OnClickListener.findViewByID()` that doesn't exist.

My suggestion is to define the EditText outside the OnClickListener. To do this, add `EditText txt_username;` before your onCreate() function and then put `txt_username = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.txt_username);` before `btn.setOnClickListener()`.

Here's the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    EditText txt_username;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

        txt_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_OK);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent data = new Intent();

                data.setData(Uri.parse(txt_username.getText().toString()));
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

}
```