# Android getPrefernces(int) is undefined

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

**after doing research and trying too look at stackoverflow solutions and try to applay them and failed in all, this error is still appers.
Iam trying to save data by using SharedPreferences and getPrefernces.

**how can i use it as an array for 10 cells only?(so it will save last ten values ive enterd and i could do sorting by max value)

Code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPrefernces(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.namep);
        editor.putString(name.getText().toString(), score);
        editor.commit();

    }
```

In the first line (the defind of sharedPref) ive got this error:
The method getPrefernces(int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Ive tried to switch it in few ways no ones works, i cant even call getActivity()function after this. i dont know why my code extends Activity.
Ive tried this soultions:
[How to resolve an error: getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779850/how-to-resolve-getsharedpreferences-error-of-the-method-getsharedpreferencesstr)

[The method setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type imageButton1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247331/the-method-setonclicklistenernew-view-onclicklistener-is-undefined-for-the)

Comment: preferences is misspelled..

Comment: getPreferences still now working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

or

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside the `OnClickListner` will be pointing to that anonymous class, not the `Activity`. So you have to use your `Activity` reference over there instead.

Change

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPrefernces(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = Your_Activity_Name.this.getPrefernces(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it in anonymous class OnClickListener and your "this" points to it. You need to call the method like this

```
OuterActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

or

```
OuterFragment.this.getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Is there a diffrent if i just do = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); to OuterFragment.this.getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: "OuterFragment.this./OuterActivity.this" is optional

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the method with the Context object. What is "this" in the above code? Then try @Piotr code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use

```
this.getPrefernces(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

in View.onClickListener because that is not the same instance.
Instead of this you have to use something like that:

```
public void click(View v) {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
//Your other code
}
```

Point is that you have to get sharedPreferrences from activity, not from onClickListener.